# Is there a cross-browser method to suppress enter on most input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added the script below to a JSF application, the page in question contains a few popup windows with forms that get submitted event when invisible when the user is pressing enter while in a input-field on the base page.

Developing with Chrome this works, but Firefox doesn't supply the event's `srcElement.id` fields.

What would be the correct (and browser independent) way to filter the fields?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
      if (code == 13) {
          // Allow return in multi-line text controls
          if ( e.srcElement.id == 'form:create:ctext' || e.srcElement.id == 'form:edit:etext' ) {
              return;
          }
          // Disable Submit on return
          e.preventDefault();
      }
   });
 });
```

Comment: `e.srcElement` should be `e.target` in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `e.srcElement` which only *some* browsers support, use `e.target` which is widely supported in most browsers and in FF of course.

Comment: Thank you, to be fully compatible with my snippet, the attribut name is required  `e.target.name`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you need to use e.target which should work in most browsers.
To get full compatibility, use:

```
function getTarget(obj) {
    var targ;
    var e=obj;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    return targ;
}
```

Source for the code snippet is [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

[EDIT]
Due to jQuery normalazing the event object, this only applies when not using jQuery. Otherwise you can stick with e.target;

Comment: In jQuery event object is normalized, no need to detect any specific feature.

Comment: It wasn't specifically stated that the answer can rely on jQuery being present, but you are right, should have mentioned that this only applies when not using jQuery. Edited now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This prevents enter button for whole page.

```
$('html').bind('keypress', function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    return false;
}
});
```